# Is there any way to perform string_replace function before laravel compiles view?

Tags: php, database, laravel, compilation, laravel-blade

I have an website that that uses mass **scraping** of a database and a CRM to perform the task, Few days ago all the crawl website moved to another website link. I just need to perform string replace task before blade compiles it other wise i had to manually change it all other locations. and the database also.

It goes like this.

```
https://somedomain.com/?qsa=sada&sda=asda
```

To

```
https://newsomedomain.com/?qsa=sada&sda=asda
```

I tried some compile methods but i failed. Can someone help me.

The service developed in larvel - v7, Mysql - v8, php - v7.4

Comment: Considering all of the poor English in the question, the suggested edit makes a weak attempt to be the "final edit".  I have rejected the edit on this basis.  Definitely not worthy of 2 rep points.

Comment: "before blade compiles". Right, but blade templates allow variable data, and the view is always rendered with this variable data anyway. So what's the big deal in just performing a string replace inside your blade template?